# Writing a conditional If-statement for portfolio analysis

Tags: r, if-statement, portfolio

I am new to R and I am currently trying to create equal-weighted portfolios based on specific Scores, but I am having some trouble with parts of the code. I have created separate data frames for top and bottom Score Contributors, and calculated the monthly returns. The dataset now looks something like this:

```
                              Company  Year      Score  Date     Return Market Value
                              Company x 2008     26.26 2008-01-01  -0.32       601.26
                              Company x 2008     26.26 2008-02-01  -0.10       410.65
                              Company x 2008     26.26 2008-03-01  -0.06       369.80
                              Company x 2008     26.26 2008-04-01   0.01       348.15
                              Company x 2008     26.26 2008-05-01   0.28       353.10
                              Company x 2008     26.26 2008-06-01  -0.25       452.43
                              Company x 2008     26.26 2008-07-01   0.11       338.91
                              Company x 2008     26.26 2008-08-01   0.15       376.86
                              Company x 2008     26.26 2008-09-01  -0.12       433.62
                              Company x 2008     26.26 2008-10-01  -0.27       383.72
                              Company x 2008     26.26 2008-11-01  -0.25       281.95
                              Company x 2008     26.26 2008-12-01  -0.17       211.20
```

My final goal is to subtract the low performing portfolio from the high, to see if the high portfolio deliver abnormal returns. For this I would like to write an *if* function that allows me to specify that if the Market Value > 0 in the *previous* month, then I want my return column to be multiplied with the corresponding weights column. I have this problem as some of the companies in my dataset are delisted during the year, and the weights then need to be redistributed to the remaining companies for the remaining months of the year. 
Various websites have been of great help (especially this one: https://www.codingfinance.com/post/2018-04-05-portfolio-returns/), but I cannot seem to find a solution to my above-mentioned problem. All help is appreciated and I apologise if the code is messy, thank you.

```
  returnhigh <- highport %>%
    group_by(Company) %>%
    # Trying to add the weight constraint 
    if(test$`Market Value` > 0) {
      # This is the part where I struggle to specify the market value of the previous month 
      returnhigh$Weight <- 1/length(highport$Company)
    }

  returnhigh <- returnhigh %>% mutate(wt_return = Weight * Return)
  porthigh <- returnhigh %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(port_ret = sum(wt_return))
  returnlow <- lowport %>%
    group_by(Company) %>%
    if(test$`Market Value` > 0) {
      # Same problem as above 
      returnlow$Weight <- 1/length(lowport$Company)
    }
  returnlow <- returnlow %>% mutate(wt_return = Weight * Return)
  portlow <- returnlow %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(port_ret = sum(wt_return))
  result <- porthigh - portlow
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be really hard for people to help you based on the code you give. Adding some example dataset and your desired output will be awesome.

Comment: Thank you Frank, I have added some more context now. Please let me know if there are anything else I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to parse out exactly what you're looking for, and I don't have a finance background, but something like this might help:

```
library(dplyr)

# High Returns
returnhigh <- df %>%
  group_by(Company) %>%
  filter(`Market Value` > 0) %>%
  mutate(Weight = 1/length(Company)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(wt_return = Weight * Return)

# Low Returns
returnlow <- df %>%
  group_by(Company) %>%
  filter(`Market Value` < 0) %>%
  mutate(Weight = 1/length(Company)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(wt_return = Weight * Return)

# Port Function to summarise your high and low returns

port_func <- function (x) {
  x <- x %>%
    group_by(Date) %>%
    summarise(port_ret = sum(wt_return))
  }

porthigh <- port_func(returnhigh)
portlow <- port_func(returnlow)
```

## Dput:

```
df <- structure(list(Company = c("Company x", "Company x", "Company x", 
"Company x", "Company x", "Company x", "Company x", "Company x", 
"Company x", "Company x", "Company x", "Company x"), Year = c(2008, 
2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008
), Score = c(26.26, 26.26, 26.26, 26.26, 26.26, 26.26, 26.26, 
26.26, 26.26, 26.26, 26.26, 26.26), Date = c("2008-01-01", "2008-02-01", 
"2008-03-01", "2008-04-01", "2008-05-01", "2008-06-01", "2008-07-01", 
"2008-08-01", "2008-09-01", "2008-10-01", "2008-11-01", "2008-12-01"
), Return = c(-0.32, -0.1, -0.06, 0.01, 0.28, -0.25, 0.11, 0.15, 
-0.12, -0.27, -0.25, -0.17), `Market Value` = c(601.26, 410.65, 
369.8, 348.15, 353.1, 452.43, 338.91, 376.86, 433.62, 383.72, 
281.95, 211.2)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```